# Full width tabs using Bootstrap (Support IE)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to adjust Bootstrap tabs to make them span the full width of their container. Here's my code (a minimal working example):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Full Width Tabs using Bootstrap</title>
        <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .full-width-tabs > ul.nav.nav-tabs {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                table-layout: fixed; /* To make all "columns" equal width regardless of content */
            }
            .full-width-tabs > ul.nav.nav-tabs > li {
                float: none;
                display: table-cell;
            }
            .full-width-tabs > ul.nav.nav-tabs > li > a {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tabbable full-width-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab-one" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-two" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-one">
                    I'm in Tab 1.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-two">
                    Howdy, I'm in Tab 2. Howdy, I'm in Tab 2. Howdy, I'm in Tab 2. Howdy, I'm in Tab 2. 
                </div>  
            </div> 
        </div> <!-- /tabbable -->

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get this (undesired) result:

[image: Undesired tabs]

However, I want the tab "headers" to span the entire width of the tab container - and distribute their individual width's evenly, something like this *desired* result:

[image: desired tabs]

How do I achieve that?

**Update 1:** Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agib/FZy4n/

**Update 2:** I already had a working widget using custom javascript. However, I'm looking for a solution that integrates seemlessly with Bootstrap and thus relies only on standard Bootstrap javascript.

**Update 3:** If I remove / comment out

```
 /* table-layout: fixed; */
```

header widths are taking up all horizontal space as needed. However, their widths are resulting from the length of the header texts and thus not distributed evenly.

This is *not* what I want either:

[image: undesired tabs]

**Update 4:** The upcoming Bootstrap 3 appears to have full-width tabs as a standard component using the class `.nav-justified`: [Bootstrap 3 -> Navs -> Justified nav](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified)

Comment: It's like there is horizontal space for an extra tab "header" before and after the actual headers, but I can't figure out where that should come from.

Comment: How many tabs do you want? Only 2?

Comment: Yeah, using Bootstrap 3 is the real solution, besides none of the answers given do that across all browsers. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Maybe I've found your solution:

Create that class with css:

```
.take-all-space-you-can{
    width:100%;
}
```

And then apply that class to your `li` tags into your `ul`. Doing these all the `li` takes the space that they can and automatically divide the space in the single row.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FZy4n/4/)

Comment: It seems to work! And to avoid adding extra classes (`.take-all-space-you-can`) not in Bootstrap I can just apply the `width: 100%` directly to the `li` tags, like this: [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agib/aCMc2/)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your solution works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari for Windows, but unfortunately not i IE9 or 10.

Comment: In IE9/10 the first tab takes up _all_ the available horizontal space.

Comment: @agibsen You want to divide the # of tabs by 100.  So two tabs you would add width="50%".  Tested and works.

Answer (score 70):

Twitter Bootstrap 3 contains a class for this, the **`nav-justified`** class.

Use it like so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @blackhawk Is this a part of Bootstrap 4 too? I haven't had a chance to use it yet

Comment: @JMK i'm almost 100% sure as the Bootstrap 4 documentation that talks about the use of tabs, has that same css class name in their demos located here - http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs

Comment: Works for Bootstrap 4 too, should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use javascript and jquery.

Building on Nick Bull's answer above, you can dynamically determine the number of tabs on the page using Jquery.

Try this on your html page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var numTabs = $('.nav-tabs').find('li').length;
       var tabWidth = 100 / numTabs;
       var tabPercent = tabWidth + "%";
       $('.nav-tabs li').width(tabPercent);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I can in any way avoid introducing extra javascript, I would like that. Actually, I had a fully functional full width tabs widget by using custom javascript, however, I'm aiming to make a widget that can rely only the standard Bootstrap javascript. Sorry, if that wasn't clear from my question.

Comment: i reduced 100 to 99 to fit width but in general it works... thanx

Comment: Simplified: $('.nav-tabs li').width((100 / $('.nav-tabs').find('li').length) + '%');

Answer (score 5):

**Bootstrap 4**

It's now very simple to get full-width Tabs using the `nav-fill` class. This works on all modern browsers including IE 11.

To get **full width** tabs, use (sized by tab content):

```
  <ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab1" data-target="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab1" data-target="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">Profile</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab3" data-target="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/5GSpMkMziV/full-width-tabs)

To get **full *equal* width** tabs, use `nav-justified`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
     <li class="nav-item">...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.nav-tabs > li {
    float:none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
.nav-tabs > li {
    /* width = (100 / number of tabs). This example assumes 3 tabs. */
    width:33.33333%;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to specify the number of tabs upfront. I want the tab widget to distribute the entire width between (in principle any number of) tabs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, just one line of code to achieve that.

```
.full-width-tabs > ul > li {   width: 100%;  }
```

It will make the tabs to span full width of their container.

Look at jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BhGKf/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for all '.nav-pills' and each 'li' element inside with double loop.

```
function(){
$('.nav.nav-tabs').each(function(){
    var liGroup = $(this).children('li');
    var liLength= liGroup.length;
    liGroup.each(function(){
        var liWidth = 100/liLength-1;
        $(this).css({'min-width': liWidth+'%','margin-left':'0px','margin-right':'0px'});
    });
});}
```

[DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/5mrcn0tb/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
        flex: auto;
}
    
.nav-tabs .nav-link {
        flex: auto;
}
</style>
```

This is what i was looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).