# Full width tabs with sufficient space to each tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have `bootstrap` `tabs` in my view that represents day of week. Tabs take width by content in the tab and its not occupying the full `width` in the page.

[image]

My requirement is full width tabs. I googled for it and found several answers but all of them giving equal width to each tab ([Full width tabs using Bootstrap (Support IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550570/full-width-tabs-using-bootstrap)). Answers are good but in my case one tab is not getting sufficient space and hence content is split into two lines (Wednesday, July 16).

[image]

So how to create full width tabs with sufficient space to each tab? Today tab have space available that space can be given to other tabs.

**EDIT.....................................................................................**

Using `bootstrap 2.3.2`

Comment: may be you can use free width first. than get the most larger width to apply them all. not a good solution but a hack.

Comment: I can not give hardcoded width to any tab. To make it responsive I need to use `%` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's bootstrap, you should be able to use the `nav-justified` class.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified

[image: nav-justified]

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using bootstrap 2.3.2 and there is no `nav-justified` class. So I download the latest bootstrap and copy paste that `nav-justified` `css` to my custom css and bingo. Thanks..,.

Answer (score 1):

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZdU8j/
The main properties are `display: table-cell` and `width: 1%`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li class="extraWidth"><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messagesssssss</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
.nav-tabs li {
    width: 24%;
}
.extraWidth {
    width: 28%;
}
</style>
```

You should provide some percentage of width for all and extra percentage of width for larger `tab`. Make sure that total width percentage should be 100%.